# Spring security core and grails with g tags

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using

```
<sec:username/>
```

to return the username of the currently logged in user in a gsp.

But how do I use some attributes of the currently logged in user? For example:

```
    <p>Name: ${user?.firstname}</p>
```

I thought `user?` would return the currently logged in user, but it does not seem to work.
What I am actually wanting to use this for is as follows:

```
 <g:each var="child" in="${user?.children}">
    <p>Name: ${child.firstname}</p>
    <p>Author: ${child.lastname}</p>
 </g:each>
```

Where `user?` is the currently logged in user. I have also tried it without the '?'. (user.children) and (User.children) none work.

FYI my Spring security classes are **User** and **UserRole**.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SIMPLIFIED SPRING SECURITY WITH GRAILS](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/). Spend more attention on SpringSecurityService. To take a logged in user you shold write in controller and pass the instance to view:

```
User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
```